# The split() method in Java does not work on a dot (.)

Tags: java, string, split

I have prepared a simple code snippet in order to separate the erroneous portion from my web application.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.print("\nEnter a string:->");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String temp = br.readLine();

        String words[] = temp.split(".");

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(words[i] + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested it while building a web application JSF. I just want to know why in the above code `temp.split(".")` does not work. The statement,

```
System.out.println(words[i]+"\n");
```

displays nothing on the console means that it doesn't go through the loop. When I change the argument of the `temp.split()` method to other characters, It works just fine as usual. What might be the problem?

Comment: Escape it. Split works on a regex

Comment: Yikes, it *defaults* to regular expressions in Java?

Answer (score 556, accepted):

[`java.lang.String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) splits on regular expressions, and `.` in a regular expression means "any character".

Try `temp.split("\\.")`.

Answer (score 77):

The [documentation on `split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) says:

> Splits this string around matches of the given **[regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)**.

(Emphasis mine.)

A dot is a special character in regular expression syntax. Use [`Pattern.quote()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) on the parameter to split() if you want the split to be on a literal string pattern:

```
String[] words = temp.split(Pattern.quote("."));
```

Comment: This does it!. And Pattern.quote(..) makes your code more readable.

Comment: It worked for me, I was facing issues while using Dot and the double slash(" || ").

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
String words[]=temp.split("\\.");
```

The method is:

```
String[] split(String regex)
```

"." is a reserved char in regex

Answer (score 11):

The method takes a regular expression, not a string, and the dot has a special meaning in regular expressions. Escape it like so `split("\\.")`. You need a double backslash, the second one escapes the first.

Answer (score 6):

`\\.` is the simple answer. Here is simple code for your help.

```
while (line != null) {
    //             
    String[] words = line.split("\\.");
    wr = "";
    mean = "";
    if (words.length > 2) {
        wr = words[0] + words[1];
        mean = words[2];

    } else {
        wr = words[0];
        mean = words[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It works fine.  Did you read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)?  The string is converted to a regular expression.

`.` is the special character matching all input characters.

As with any regular expression special character, you escape with a `\`.  You need an additional `\` for the Java string escape.

Answer (score 3):

```
    private String temp = "mahesh.hiren.darshan";

    String s_temp[] = temp.split("[.]");

  Log.e("1", ""+s_temp[0]);
```