# split from full stop in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The split() method in Java does not work on a dot (.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935858/the-split-method-in-java-does-not-work-on-a-dot)

I'm new to java. I want to split a String from "." (dot) and get those names one by one. But this program gives error:  `"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0"`
please help me

```
 String input1 = "van.bus.car";

 System.out.println(input.split(".")[0]+"");

 System.out.println(input.split(".")[1]+"");

 System.out.println(input.split(".")[2]+"");
```

Comment: it is probably worth keeping the string array returned from your split call, and maybe add a test or read the values from the array in a loop to ensure that you are not trying to get a value that does not exist in your array

Answer (score 21):

In regex, `Dot(.)` is a special meta-character which matches `everything`.

Since [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) works on Regex, so you need to escape it with backslash if you want to match a `dot`.

```
System.out.println(input.split("\\.")[0]+"");
```

To learn more about Regex, refer to following sites: -

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 7):

The argument to [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is a regex, and so the full stop/dot/`.` has a special meaning: *match any character*.  To use it literally in your split, you'll need to escape it:

```
String[] splits = input1.split("\\.");
```

That should give you an array of length 3 for your input string.

For more about regex and which characters are special, see the [docs for Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).