# Split function doesn't work

Tags: java, string, split

Here is a function which take a long String and return a string divided in paragraph.

The problem is that k is empty. Why `split()` function doesn't work?

```
private String ConvertSentenceToParaGraph(String sen) {
    String nS = "";
    String k[] = sen.split(".");

    for (int i = 0; i < k.length - 1; i++) {
        nS = nS + k[i] + ".";
        Double ran = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 4);

        if (i > 0 && i % ran == 0) {
            nS = nS + "\n\n";
        }
    }
    return nS;
}
```

Comment: What is the input `sen`?

Comment: [The `split()` method in Java does not work on a dot (.)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7935858/1391249)

Answer (score 5):

[`String.split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression. A dot `.` means 'every character'. You must escape it `\\.` if you want to split on the dot character.

Answer (score 4):

`split` expects a regular expression, and `"."` is a regular expression for "any character". If you want to split on each `.` character, you need to escape it:

```
String k[] = sen.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 3):

`split()` method takes a regex. And `.` is a meta-character, which matches any character except newline. You need to escape it. Use:

```
String k[] = sen.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
sen.split(".");
```

To:

```
sen.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the dot, if you want to split on a dot:

```
String k[] = sen.split("\\.");
```

A `.` splits on the regex `.`, which means any character.

Comment: It wouldn't compile, you've to use `\\` as others have used.