# String Split method not Giving desired results

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I am trying to use Split method of String in java I have example like this.

```
String number  = Math.random() * 100 + "";
System.out.println("Number is : " + number);
String[] seprate = number.split(".");
System.out.println(seprate.length);
```

it should give me 2 Stack of array i mean 2 array element if value is like e.g. 67.90512897385857

but its not giving value like that

```
String number  = Math.random() * 100 + "";
System.out.println("Number is : " + number);
String[] seprate = number.split(".");
System.out.println(seprate.length);
System.out.println(seprate[1]);
```

its giving arrayindexoutbound exception.

Someone give idea why its giving like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `String#split` method takes a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

The `"."` in there means **any character**.

Escape your `"."` as such to signal a literal dot: `number.split("\\.")`.

As [Pieter De Bie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2545439/pieter-de-bie) points out, using `java.util.regex.Pattern` to safely escape your literals when passing literals to an argument that is going to be interpreted as a regular expression will help you a good deal.

In this case, you could use: `number.split(Pattern.quote("."))`

Comment: In addition to this answer: I alwas use string.split(Pattern.quote("possibleRegex")) to make sure that I'm not splitting on regexes

Comment: @PieterDeBie good point, will add to answer.

Comment: you're welcome, you have a small typo in my name though :p

Comment: @PieterDeBie oops. Fixing now :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the dot. The split method takes a regular expression. From the docs:

> Parameters:regex the delimiting regular expression

```
String[] seprate = number.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Split works with regex and you should use like this

```
number.split("\\.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the **documentation**:

> public String[] split(String regex)
>
> Splits this string around matches of the given **regular expression**.

In a regular expression, `.` is *any* character (except newlines, usually).

So **you are splitting at every character**.

If you want to match only a dot, `"\\."` will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Double f = Math.random() * 100;
        String number  = String.valueOf(f);
        System.out.println("Number is : " + number);
        String[] seprate = number.split("\\.");
        System.out.println(seprate.length);
```

Please use this link for ur question.

[The split() method in Java does not work on a dot (.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935858/the-split-method-in-java-does-not-work-on-a-dot)