# split string by period and quotation marks in java

Tags: java, string, split

A very dumb question, I know " and . are both special characters, but why there is a difference when using split() function?

so here is the code

```
    String.split("\"");
    String.split("\\.");
```

They both works, but why there is only one "\" in first line of code and two in second?

Edit:
What would happen if I do

```
    String.split("\\"");
```

Would the result be the same as

```
    String.split("\"");
```

Comment: _I know " and . are both special characters_ : No, at least not under the same context.  `"` is special as in Java's String literal syntax, but nothing special in regex.  `.`is special in aspect of regex, but not in Java's String literal syntax.  Just print out that two strings and you should see what that means

Comment: Simply: the parameter in the first line has length 1 (the only character is "), and the parameter in the second line has length 2 (the first character is \ and the second character is a period).  The regex matcher needs the \ to be in the string so that it doesn't treat the period as special.

Answer (score 5):

In the first example, you are escaping the `"` (which isn't a special regex character, so it's literally the same as `string.split(Character.toString('"'));`) - that is, you need to escape the `"` to put `"` in a `String` - you could also write `string.split("" + '"');`. In the second example, you are escaping the `.` (which is a special regex character). Thus the `\` is escaped, and is equivalent to `Pattern.compile(".", Pattern.LITERAL).split(string);`

Answer (score 2):

When you use split function in Java you should also take care that some symbols means more than just simple character, it might also means special command for regex.

```
For string    For regex
   "\""           "      <- noting special from regex point of view, will process all (")
   "."            .      <- Yeh, special character, I will process all characters
   "\\."          \.     <- noting special from regex point of view, will process all (.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Already answered here [The split() method in Java does not work on a dot (.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935858/the-split-method-in-java-does-not-work-on-a-dot)

`java.lang.String.split` splits on regular expressions, and `.` in a regular expression means "any character".