# Split A string using "," but not ", " in java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I have a String like this:

```
123,TV,August 14, 2020,"This is a fantasy series, and top rated"
```

I'm using String.split() on this but my delimiter should only separate the string based on comma with no trailing space.

Expected Output

```
["123","TV","August 14, 2020","This is a fantasy series, and top rated"]
```

Actual Output

```
["123","TV","August 14"," 2020","This is a fantasy series", " and top rated"]
```

It is splitting the strings considering all the commas. I just want to consider the commas with no trailing space or double quotes(").

Can someone please advice me on this?

Comment: You should get whoever is producing the string to quote the date field where it contains a comma, i.e. `123,TV,"August 14, 2020","This is a fantasy series, and top rated"`. Then it's in a valid CSV format, so you can use a CSV library to read it e.g. Apache Commons CSV.

Comment: Use `text.split(",(?!\\s)")`

Comment: Have you done *any* prior research? There are really a lot of questions that explain how to use spit with regular expressions, like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935858/the-split-method-in-java-does-not-work-on-a-dot

Comment: You can try 

> String splitBy = ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)";

it will split by comma and eliminate comma inside double quotes.
If you research more you could get it in google very common problem.

Comment: ["123","TV","August 14, 2020",""This is a fantasy series, and top rated""]....I also want to remove "" that remain in the string after split

Answer (score 0):

You may combine with a `Negative Lookahead` `(?!\s)` to assert there is no space afte the comma

```
String s = "123,TV,August 14, 2020 ,\"This is a fantasy series, and top rated\"";
List<String> parts = Arrays.stream(s.split(",(?!\\s)"))
        .map(x -> x.replaceAll("^[\"\\s]|[\"\\s]$", ""))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
for (String p : parts) {
    System.out.println(">>" + p + "<<");
}

>>123<<
>>TV<<
>>August 14, 2020<<
>>This is a fantasy series, and top rated<<
```

Comment: Hi azro, thanks for the repsonse, this works. But I want a regex with a combination of comma without leading space, comma with leading double quotes and double quotes with leading comma. Could you tell me the regex for this?

Comment: @IshanPathak You can't just add requirements after ^^ edit your initial to post what input/output you want, and I'll see –

Comment: @IshanPathak i've add a replaceAll in my solutin, see